# F# constructor constraint

Tags: f#

Whilst attempting to learn the use of [constructor constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints), I was hoping that something like the following was possible.

```
type Foo<'T when 'T : (new : int -> 'T)> = {Bar: 'T}
```

But this does not compile, simply returning the error

> 'new' constraints must take one argument of type 'unit' and return the constructed type

It seems as though the constraint should be called "parameterless constructor constraint" because I cant get any other form beyond this to compile.

```
type Foo<'T when 'T : (new : unit-> 'T)> = {Bar: 'T}
```

Can a constructor constraint be used to constrain the generic types constructor to have a specific signature other than `unit` ?

Comment: This is a limitation of .NET. It only supports parameterless constructors as constraints.

Comment: Seems rather expressive syntax to support only a single option. I wonder if the F# compiler can handler more, (thus the expressiveness) but is constrained to a single case for now until the .NET limitation is removed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, .NET support for constraints is limited and only supports (i) paremeter-less constructors and (ii) implementation of an interface.

F# follows the same restructions for ordinary generic type parameters, but it also has statically resolved type parameters written as `^T`, which can have more expressive constraints. Those are not compiled to .NET constraints, but instead, are erased during the compilation, so there are other constraints on those.

An example akin to what you have using static memnber constraints would look something like this:

```
type Foo<'T> = 
  { Bar : 'T }
  static member inline Demo< ^S when ^S : (static member Create : int -> ^S)>() = 
    { Bar = (^S : (static member Create : int -> ^S) (10)) }
```

The constrains need to be on an inline member (or inline function), so I'm defining a generic type `Foo<'T>` which has a static member `Demo` that can be called with any type that has a `Create` method taking an int. For example:

```
type Sample(n:int) =
  member x.N = n
  static member Create(n:int) = Sample(n)
```

We can now call `Foo.Demo` with `Sample` as the type argument and we get `Foo<Sample>` back, created using `10` as the initialization value:

```
let f = Foo<_>.Demo<Sample>()
```

Comment: I had read about statically resolved types, but not joined the dots, thinking that type constraints were only used in generic type definitions. You have cleared my confusion. Thanks.